# int and long cast in loop for array

Tags: java, arrays, size

I'm trying to understand. What will happen as n passes from int range to long int range and why doesn't this pose a conflict for the compiler? I'm intending to use this to create an array of size n (I know it will take massive amounts of memory and it's not meant to  to the final value) which I believe can only by indexed by int and not long although so far no errors from eclipse. Help understanding would be great thanks.

```
for (int n= 10; n <= ((long)(500*Math.pow(10,6))); n=n*2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop as such does not see n as anything other than an int, it manipulates n in

```
n = n * 2
```

but here it's an int, so you'll get overflow behaviour n will never exceed the maximum int value.

In evaluating the termination condition the for loop needs a boolean

```
 n <= ((long)(500*Math.pow(10,6)))
```

that is an int compared with a long, so n is converted to a long only for the purpose of evaluating the comparison think of this as

```
 long tmp = n;
 if ( tmp <= bigLongValue)
```

n itself is not affected.

Comment: 500 * 10^6 as well as the double of it is less than Integer.MAX_VALUE.  That's why the loop terminates.

Comment: I also put a break statement in because I don't have to power to run it up to 500 * 10^6

Comment: I'm using n to determine the size of an array. Could n grow above Integer.MAX_VALUE if I were to change the exit condition and if it is possible would the program crash immediately?

Comment: if n is an int the biggest it could get to be in Integer.MAX_VALUE, and that's pretty big. If you make any object sufficiently big then your JVM can run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Even an int is not required

Try this
    for(float t=0; t<=2;t=t+1){
    System.out.println(t);
    }

So for loop is irrespective of the values and types

and to create an infinite loop

for(;;){
}

can be used.